# RestKit mapping for JSOG API object

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, restkit, jsog

I'm trying to figure out how to realize a mapping of an `API` response into CoreData objects using [RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit). The `API` uses [JSOG](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsog#serializing-to-jsog) standard. Here is an example:

```
[
    {
        "@id": "1",
        "name": "Sally",
        "friend": {
            "@id": "2",
            "name": "Bob",
            "friend": {
                "@id": "3",
                "name": "Fred",
                "friend": { "@ref": "1" }
            }
        }
    },
    { "@ref": "2" },
    { "@ref": "3" }
]
```

How would I create an `RKEntityMapping` for such a `JSON`? Mapping of simple attributes is trivial, the question is how to setup the relationships here so they work with `@ref`, also, when the top level user object contains the `@ref` only.

```
RKEntityMapping *userMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"Question"
                                                   inManagedObjectStore:[RKObjectManager sharedManager].managedObjectStore];

[userMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@
 {
     @"@id" : @"identifier",
     @"name" : @"name"
 }];

[userMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"friend"
                                                                            toKeyPath:@"friend"
                                                                          withMapping:userMapping]];
```

My guess is that i could use code below to handle the `@ref` inside of an object:

```
[userMapping addConnectionForRelationship:@"friend" connectedBy:@{@"@ref": @"@id"}];
```

but is it correct?

1. How would I map either a full object or just a reference to an already-provided object (via `@ref`) to actual Core Data objects?
2. How can I map the top elements of the JSON (being a list of `User` objects) to an actual list of `User` entities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a relationship using the mapping itself, so it drills recursively. Use foreign key mapping for the refs.

---

Looking at this again following your comment it may actually be a good candidate for a dynamic mapping instead of foreign key. This would mean creating a new mapping which just uses `@"@ref" : @"identifier"` for the connections and a dynamic mapping which looks at the keys and decides wether to use this connection mapping or the full `userMapping`.

Note that both of these mappings need to specify that `identifier` is the unique key of the object and you should use a memory cache to allow the existing objects to be found instead of creating duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! I made progress but I think I'm not fully getting it. I updated my question clarifying what blocks me now. Please have a look. How would I create the foreign key mapping?

Comment: I'm in the same situation as @Bearwithme and Wain's proposition works like a charm! There is however one thing I'd like to know: Is it not possible to prefix keypaths with an `@` symbol?

Comment: I do seem to recall it being an issue due to KVC @ahaese

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! It really helped!